# Python asyncio REPL behavior vs normal REPL behavior

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm struggling to understand the difference between these two situations. In a script, I am getting TimeoutErrors from the below websockets.client.connect function, and I can replicate that behavior in a normal python REPL. However, it connects and works correctly in a python asyncio repl [(python -m asyncio)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/__main__.py).

```py
# $ python -m asyncio # Python repl executing asyncio.__main__ 
import asyncio
import websockets.client as wsc
import ssl # Without this, similar looking error!
wss_url = '' # My WSS url
ws = await wsc.connect(wss_url) # This works
await ws.send('data') # This works
```

```py
# $ python # either in REPL or when executing a script with the below
import asyncio
import websockets.client as wsc
import ssl
wss_url = '' # My WSS url

# ws = asyncio.run(wsc.connect(wss_url)) # Doesn't work, bc wsc.connect isn't a coroutine

async def get_ws():
    return await wsc.connect(wss_url)
ws = asyncio.run(get_ws())
# Raises asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError

async def main():
    async with wsc.connect(wss_url) as ws:
        print("Connected: websocket")
    # or ws = await wsc.connect(wss_url), same result
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
# Raises asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError, prints nothing
```

What is asyncio doing when run in main that's not being executed here?
The vague struggles of others suggest that there might be a sleep() call missing, or needing to create or get a loop(), but asyncio.run() seems to be sufficient for simpler tests, not using websockets. There's a similar error for the asyncio repl if ssl is not imported; is there a globals difference?

In this particular case, python 3.8, websockets  11.0.3.

Comment: This sounds like it might not have anything to do with asyncio - it might be a problem on the other end, or a problem with your network, or you might have mistyped the URL or something.

Comment: I'd like to think so; but I can repeatedly, consistently, everytime get the connection to work from python -m asyncio, and never from a script. So perhaps its might be a websockets thing as well, with some behavior with defaults and ssl?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not satisfied with this answer, because it doesn't really answer the question, but it avoids the problem (somehow) that caused the question.

Using the websockets threading api, and not the asyncio api, the problem goes away. (But you might be mixing then asyncio and threading code, YMMV). Here's a working example using the threading api (the initial re-connecting for network robustness):

```py
import websockets.sync.client as wsc_sync
from contextlib import closing

ws = None
while ws is None:
    try:
        ws = wsc_sync.connect(wss_url) # YMMV: open_timeout=20.0
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Connection failure, retrying websocket:\t{e}')
with closing(ws):
    print("Connected: websocket " + wss_url)
```